# SVN Migration to another Windows Server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnadmin

I attempting to relocate multiple SVN repositories from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2016. Using svnadmin dump and svnadmin load are not preserving the revision numbering. How can I relocate the repositories and preserve the numbering?

Comment: Why not just copy all the files?

Comment: **Show used commands pair with output** in process, we aren't psychics here. Plain dump+load must work, as shown, f.e.  @ https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin